# Grafana gauge for percentage error rate not showing correct calculation

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql, grafana-loki

I am trying to visualize the percentage of requests that resulted in error (minute by minute) via a Grafana gauge but the Gauge is not showing the correct value.
For example when I execute 10 requests within a 1 minute interval - where 5 of those requests result in HTTP 200 and 5 result in HTTP 500 then I expect the Gauge to show 50% error percentage.
However the value stays at 100% regardless that I have been sending successful and unsuccessful requests to the API :

[image: gauge]

This is the corresponding query :

```
100 * (sum(sum_over_time(total_requests_gauge{status_code!="200"}[1m]))/ on() group_left() sum(sum_over_time(total_requests_gauge[1m])))
```

I have configured the Gauge unit to Percent :

[image: percent]

On the client side this is how I have set up the Prometheus exporter :

MetricsReporter.cs

```
public class MetricReporter
{
private readonly ILogger<MetricReporter> _logger;
private readonly Counter _requestCounter;
private readonly Gauge _requestGauge;
private readonly Histogram _responseTimeHistogram;
    public MetricReporter(ILogger<MetricReporter> logger)
{
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));

    _requestCounter = Metrics.CreateCounter("total_requests", "The total number of requests serviced by this API.");
    _requestGauge = Metrics.CreateGauge("total_requests_gauge", "The total number of requests serviced by this API.");

    _responseTimeHistogram = Metrics.CreateHistogram("request_duration_seconds",
        "The duration in seconds between the response to a request.", new HistogramConfiguration
        {
            Buckets = Histogram.ExponentialBuckets(0.01, 2, 10),
            LabelNames = new[] { "status_code", "method" , "path"}
        });
}

public void RegisterRequest()
{
    _requestCounter.Inc();
    _requestGauge.Inc();
}

public void RegisterResponseTime(int statusCode, string method,string path, TimeSpan elapsed)
{
    _responseTimeHistogram.Labels(statusCode.ToString(), method, path).Observe(elapsed.TotalSeconds);
}
```

}

Prometheus is scrapping the metrics correctly at ***http://localhost:9090*** as well as the API endpoint at *http://localhost:80/metrics*

I also have an endpoint that always returns error responses :

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("problem")]
    public IActionResult Problem([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
    {
        //always returns HTTP 500 error      
            return Problem();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong prometheus function for this use case - sum_over_time(). Rather I would increase() for easy calculation.

The increase() calculates how much a counter increased in the specified interval. The sum_over_time() calculates the sum of all values in the specified interval.

Here is the query that I tested and worked fine for me:

> sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{namespace="",pod_name=~"",uri=~"",status!="200"}[1m]))/sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{namespace="",pod_name=~"",uri=~""}[1m]))
> *100

Looks like you are using a custom metric, so change the metric name and filter params accordingly.

Comment: This is working perfectly. However I am not sure about the caveat that we should never use increase and rate function with gauges because  "these functions make calculations based on the assumption that the value only ever goes up"  https://tomgregory.com/how-and-when-to-use-a-prometheus-gauge/     because for my case the Error rate may sometimes go down depending on the proportion of requests that resulted in non HTTP 200 status over the last minute. I have tested this and its working perfectly , the gauge % goes down as long as the proportion of erroneous requests is lower in the last minute